# Shorter code (Arrays/If-statements)

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, equals

All I have to know is how to write this code shorter (if possible).
Could someone take a look to it?

I couldn't find how I could write it in a shorter way, but maybe someone knows a way to do it.
Maybe I can put all this code in only 1 If-statement or something?

```
String arrayWoord[]=new String[10];
arrayWoord[0] = letterVeld1.getText();
arrayWoord[1] = letterVeld2.getText();
arrayWoord[2] = letterVeld3.getText();
arrayWoord[3] = letterVeld4.getText();
arrayWoord[4] = letterVeld5.getText();
arrayWoord[5] = letterVeld6.getText();
arrayWoord[6] = letterVeld7.getText();
arrayWoord[7] = letterVeld8.getText();
arrayWoord[8] = letterVeld9.getText();
arrayWoord[9] = letterVeld10.getText();
if (arrayWoord[0].equals("")) {
  toonKnop1.setVisible(false);
  letterlijnLabel1.setVisible(false);
} // end of if
if (arrayWoord[1].equals("")) {
  toonKnop2.setVisible(false);
  letterlijnLabel2.setVisible(false);
} // end of if
if (arrayWoord[2].equals("")) {
  toonKnop3.setVisible(false);
  letterlijnLabel3.setVisible(false);
} // end of if
if (arrayWoord[3].equals("")) {
  toonKnop4.setVisible(false);
  letterlijnLabel4.setVisible(false);
} // end of if
if (arrayWoord[4].equals("")) {
  toonKnop5.setVisible(false);
  letterlijnLabel5.setVisible(false);
} // end of if
if (arrayWoord[5].equals("")) {
  toonKnop6.setVisible(false);
  letterlijnLabel6.setVisible(false);
} // end of if
if (arrayWoord[6].equals("")) {
  toonKnop7.setVisible(false);
  letterlijnLabel7.setVisible(false);
} // end of if
if (arrayWoord[7].equals("")) {
  toonKnop8.setVisible(false);
  letterlijnLabel8.setVisible(false);
} // end of if
if (arrayWoord[8].equals("")) {
  toonKnop9.setVisible(false);
  letterlijnLabel9.setVisible(false);
} // end of if
if (arrayWoord[9].equals("")) {
  toonKnop10.setVisible(false);
  letterlijnLabel10.setVisible(false);
} // end of if
```

Comment: What are the types of the `toonKnop` variables? And are the `Label`(s) JLabel(s)?

Comment: Do you use `arrayWoord` after the given code at all?

Comment: toonknop is a buton. Yes, the     Label (s) are JLabel(s). I use the     arrayWoord after the give code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `for` loop to make it shorter:

```
for (String word : arrayWoord) { 
   if (word.equals("")) {
      // put your code here..       
   }
}
```

Comment: But now you're only setting `toonKnop4` no matter which one it is, instead of the correct one.

Comment: @DM oh I thought this part: `letterlijnLabel4.setVisible(false);`  is same.. but anyway I was only giving hint on where to put code. :)) Just made changes to make it more general.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the various `Label`(s) are instances of `JLabel` and that the various `Knop`(s) are `JComponent`(s) - you could populate three arrays and use a single `for` loop. Something like,

```
String arrayWoord[] = { letterVeld1.getText(), letterVeld2.getText(), 
        letterVeld3.getText(), letterVeld4.getText(), letterVeld5.getText(), 
        letterVeld6.getText(), letterVeld7.getText(),
        letterVeld8.getText(), letterVeld9.getText(), letterVeld10.getText() };
JLabel[] letterLabels = { letterlijnLabel1, letterlijnLabel2, letterlijnLabel3, 
        letterlijnLabel4, letterlijnLabel5, letterlijnLabel6, letterlijnLabel7, 
        letterlijnLabel8, letterlijnLabel9, letterlijnLabel10 };
JComponent[] knops = { toonKnop1, toonKnop2, toonKnop3, toonKnop4, toonKnop5, 
        toonKnop6, toonKnop7, toonKnop8, toonKnop9, toonKnop10 };
for (int i = 0; i < arrayWoord.length; i++) {
    if (arrayWoord[i].isEmpty()) {
        knops[i].setVisible(false);
        letterLabels[i].setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

And, if you're using Java 8+, the `for` loop could be rewritten with an `IntStream`, a `filter` and a `forEach` like

```
IntStream.range(0, arrayWoord.length).filter(i -> arrayWoord[i].isEmpty())
            .forEach(i -> {
    knops[i].setVisible(false);
    letterLabels[i].setVisible(false);
});
```

**Note** that [`String.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) returns true iff the `String` has a length of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through arrayWooord with a for loop and put conditionals within that for loop to complete the task you're trying to do.

Comment: A `for` loop is the obvious solution, but it doesn't really make things shorter unless those other variables are also in arrays.

Comment: I mean, it'd be tedious, but he/she could make a for loop for the assigning as well

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arrayWoord = {
        letterVeld1.getText(),
        letterVeld2.getText(),
        ...
        letterVeld10.getText()
};

TypeOfLetterlijnLabels[] letterlijnLabels = {
        letterlijnLabel1,
        letterlijnLabel2,
        ...
        letterlijnLabel10
};

TypeOfToonKnop[] toonKnops = {
        toonKnop1,
        toonKnop2,
        ...
        toonKnop10
}

for(int i = 0; i < arrayWoord.length && i < letterlijnLabels.length; i++) {
    if(arrayWoord[i].equals("")) {
        toonKnops[i].setVisible(false);
        letterlijnLabels[i].setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this actually shorter, though?

Comment: it is (especially if you want to do something else with it later), but at first you should put those items in an array when making them.

Comment: One objection:  Somehow you changed `.setVisible(false)` to `.setVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

for(String string : arrayWoord) {
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(string)) {
        // get toonKnop for arrayWoord
        // get letterlijnLable for arrayWoord
    }
}
```

Comment: Your comments are doing an awful lot of work, there.

Comment: Also, aren't those two conditions in the `if` statement the same thing?

Comment: I meant for that to be an empty space. "isEmpty()" checks that the length is not "0", where "equals(" ")" would make sure that if there is a length greater than 0, that it is not just an empty string.

Comment: Although, I prefer to use apache-commons StringUtils.isBlank() in place of those 2, which checks 1) if the string is null, 2) is the length is 0, and 3) if the only character is whitespace.